# Changing Colors in WPF Style Programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

First off, I have somewhat accomplished what I am about to ask creating different styles with different Foreground/Background colors (for example) and then in the code doing either

```
Control.Style = new_style
```

or

```
this.Resources["MyStyle"] = new_style
```

I was happy with that until I hit an issue w/ the ComboBox control where I was wanting to programmatically change the color of the arrow on the dropwdown button.  This appears to get into Control Template changes to set that so I decided to approach my colors changes from another route -- setting the color values within the Style or Control Template using Binding.  So I created a test program starting simple and planning to workup to the Control Template changes but I have yet to get "simple" working.  My test program consists of a Textbox and a Button and I am trying to change the foreground color within the text box.  The basic XML code is (less some lines):

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" x:Class="ColorTest4.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FGColor" Color="{Binding fgColor}"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxStyle1}">
            <TextBox.Resources>
                <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TextBoxBorder" EndPoint="0,20" MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#ABADB3" Offset="0.05"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#E2E3EA" Offset="0.07"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#E3E9EF" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
                <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource FGColor}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}"/>
                    <!--<Some Setter Properties & Style.Triggers removed for conciseness >-->
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Resources>
        </TextBox>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="433,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then in the code I have:

```
private Color pvColor = Colors.Green;
private Color fgColor
{
    get { MessageBox.Show("fgColor");  return pvColor; }
}
```

The idea being that if I want to change the foreground color, pvColor just needs to change within the program.

For whatever reason this is not working.  I am hoping I am just overlooking something simple in the code that I have yet to see/find.  If I define fgColor in the Window.Resources as below, that works -- I get Pink text:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FGColor" Color="Pink"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Any ideas or direction would be greatly appreciate.

Thanks

Update 1:  I updated the code snippet to reflect the use of Color rather than Brush.  I have also tried Frank J's INotifyPropertyChanged option and also the Dependence Property option but neither have worked yet.  The Dependence Property complained that Color was not nullable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**-- Update**

I looked at your code again.

The problem that you have is that the color of the SolidColorBrush is changing but not the ressource itself and therefore the change doesn't get propagated.

2 possible solutions:

1) You can change the requirement from having a property set the the brushes color to make the change to changing the ressource itself which will propagate the DynamicResource change (Press the button to see the switch):

```
<Window x:Class="SOTextBoxForeground.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SOTextBoxForeground"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="MyWindow">
<Window.Resources>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FGColor" Color="Green"/>
   </Window.Resources>
   <Grid>
      <Grid.Resources>
         <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource FGColor}"/>
         </Style>
      </Grid.Resources>
      <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}" />
      <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="433,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
   </Grid>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Resources["FGColor"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    }
}
```

2) Alternatively you bind the styles Foreground directly to the variable via the converter instead of going through the Ressource (again press the button to see the change):

```
<Window x:Class="SOTextBoxForeground.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SOTextBoxForeground"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="MyWindow">
      <Window.Resources>
      <local:ColorToSolidColorBrushConverter x:Key="ColorToSolidColorBrushConverter" />
   </Window.Resources>
   <Grid>
      <Grid.Resources>
         <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=pvColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorToSolidColorBrushConverter}}"/>
         </Style>
      </Grid.Resources>
      <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}" />
      <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="433,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
   </Grid>
</Window>

public class ColorToSolidColorBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{

  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
     Color? desiredColor = value as Color?;
     if (desiredColor != null)
     {
        return new SolidColorBrush(desiredColor.Value);
     }

     //Return here your default
     return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
     return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
  }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty pvColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("pvColor",
    typeof(Color?), typeof(MainWindow),
    new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Red));

    public Color? pvColor
    {
        get { return (Color?)GetValue(pvColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(pvColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.pvColor = Colors.Blue;
    }
}

public class ColorToSolidColorBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Color? desiredColor = value as Color?;
        if (desiredColor != null)
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(desiredColor.Value);
        }

        //Return here your default
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

For both solutions change the namespace accordingly in the code.

Comment: One thing of note is that I am not to the point of changing the color -- just displaying the dialog.  There is text in the textbox but it is not colored.

Comment: Also, I actually have this in my fgColor implementation: get { MessageBox.Show("fgColor"); return new SolidColorBrush(pvColor); } -- and the message box never displays.

Comment: Dependence Property option complained that Color was not nullable.

Comment: Redid the whole answer and tested it. Both solution are tested and work and there is explanation why yours didn't work now.

Comment: Tried both versions w/ my test program and both worked.  Ultimately I would like to move the Style to an Application level resource and associate all applications Windows to that Style.  With that in mind, which of the two options would be the easiest to implement?  My thought was the first one............

Comment: Quick question: Since you say you want to be able to apply that wholesale to all Windows, do you expect it that you will change all TextBox Foregound colors in the whole application often and to many different colors? Seems an unlikely scenario to me TBH. If you want at given times the foreground to be e.g. red instead of green but want to have a mechanism to do that easily across the application I would e.g. look into triggers and attached properties instead. Also there are already validation styles attached to the Textbox. You might want to look into that before you roll your own.

Comment: Trying to allow for "user defined themes" within the application and the user would change them as they wanted -- if they wanted.  Theme 1 would be the default current Windows theme and then others would be definable and selectable to the user's liking.  Each window would be defined to use the Application Resource Style and if the user changes the App Theme, then change the App SolidColorBrush resources at that time if using Option 1 solution.

Comment: That is a tall order, I would honestly start researching how to implement Theming in WPF. If you already did and this is one of the difficulties you encountered the above solutions are the best I can come up on top of my head. And, yes I would agree the first option has the least coding overhead and seems to be more in line with what you need. DynamicResources are usually more "expensive" though because WPF has to keep track of them. I personally would look into resources that have only effect when you restart the application and see if you can make it that way via static resources though.

Comment: Static Resources would probably be doable too. My initial testing used Static Resources and I changed the style when simulating a user theme change.  Could possibly update the App Resource SolidColorBrushes and then reset the Style at the end of those changes.  I will give that a test and see.  Originally was not going to support this in the program but the program has too support at least two themes (default and one more) so the ability to have the extras is just a headache....... I mean fringe benefit............

Comment: Here is [an article](http://svetoslavsavov.blogspot.com/2009/07/switching-wpf-interface-themes-at.html) that might help for runtime switching via dynamic resources if the other solution doesn't work. Good luck.

Comment: So I have opened for Solution #2 but I am now looking at implementing the Styles as Application Resources.  I have moved the DependencyProperty/DependencyObject logic into App.xml.cs but when I try to compile I get "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty)' " error on the pvColor get and set.  I've unsuccessfully tried a few things.  Any thoughts on what I might be missing?  Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you tried to implement that statically hence the error that you need an object reference.... Try a new question -- because without actual code trying to debug based on comments is not  going to work. Start a new question and reference this one if necessary.

Comment: Moved Application Resource question to this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422001/changing-colors-in-wpf-style-programmatically-application-resource

Answer (score -1):

`SolidColorBrush.Color` expects a `Color` not another `Brush`.

```
private Color pvColor = Colors.Green;
public Color fgColor
{
    get { return pvColor; }
    set
    {
        pvColor = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("fgColor"); // Make sure you have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried color and that does not work either.  Also I actually have this in my fgColor implementation -- get { MessageBox.Show("fgColor");  return pvColor; } -- and the message box is never displayed.