# Changing Colors in WPF Style Programmatically -- Application Resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have streamlined the code some.  The `Style` definitions are more in line with what I have in the actual program that I am working on rather than all the auto generated fluff of the original samples - for both the Window Resource sample and what I am trying to move to w/ the Application Resource sample.

I have also "dotted down" the Binding to `appColors.appColor` which is based on `DependencyObject` in the Application Resource sample.  I have also played around some w/ `INotifyPropertyChanged` but have yet to get that working right.  I have tried this in both the `App` and `AppColors` classes.

Based on [Changing Colors in WPF Style Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725764/changing-colors-in-wpf-style-programmatically) I was able to change the foreground color of a text box programmatically using a converter and DependencyProperty values.  The resulting code using local Windows Resources is as follows:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" x:Name="LocalWindow" x:Class="ColorLocal.MainWindow"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ColorLocal"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="122.321" Width="269.87">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ColorToSolidColorBrushConverter x:Key="ColorToSolidColorBrushConverter" />
        <Style x:Key="LocalTextBoxStyle" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ElementName=LocalWindow, Path=localColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorToSolidColorBrushConverter}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Style="{DynamicResource LocalTextBoxStyle}"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnRed" Content="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnRed_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnGreen" Content="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="90,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnGreen_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btBlue" Content="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btBlue_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnNewWindow" Content="New Window" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnNewWindow_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace ColorLocal
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty localColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("localColor", typeof(Color?), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Purple));

        public Color? localColor
        {
            get { return (Color?)GetValue(localColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(localColorProperty, value); }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnRed_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.localColor = Colors.Red;
        }

        private void btnGreen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.localColor = Colors.Green;
        }

        private void btBlue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.localColor = Colors.Blue;
        }

        private void btnNewWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

    public class ColorToSolidColorBrushConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Color? desiredColor = value as Color?;
            if (desiredColor != null)
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(desiredColor.Value);
            }

            //Return here your default
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }
}
```

This code produces a dialog box with a TextBox with text initially colored purple, 3 Buttons labeled **Red**, **Green**, & **Blue**, and another Button labeled **New Window**.  Pressing the corresponding color button, changes the color of the text in the TextBox.  The New Window button does nothing.

I now what to move this into an **Application Resource** that I can assign to all controls on different windows and have the color change take place throughout the program.  I made the changes as detailed in the attached code segments.  I initially had a problem using DependencyObject values in the App.xaml.cs code but found another post about that.  However, the TextBox foreground color remains black even on the MainWindow TextBox (I have yet to code the logic around a New Window button press).

Any thoughts / direction would be appreciated.

I have updated the code sampleThis provided code is more in line w/ the actual coding of the

App.xaml

```
<Application
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" x:Name="LocalApp" x:Class="ColorApp.App"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ColorApp"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:ColorToSolidColorBrushConverter x:Key="ColorToSolidColorBrushConverter" />
        <Style x:Key="AppTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding appColors.appColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorToSolidColorBrushConverter}, ElementName=LocalApp}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

App.xaml.cs

```
namespace ColorApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public AppColors appColors = new AppColors();
    }

    public class AppColors : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty appColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("appColor",
                                typeof(Color?), typeof(AppColors), new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Purple));

        public Color? appColor
        {
            get { return (Color?)this.GetValue(appColorProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(appColorProperty, value); }
        }
    }

    public class ColorToSolidColorBrushConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Color? desiredColor = value as Color?;
            if (desiredColor != null)
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(desiredColor.Value);
            }

            //Return here your default
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ColorApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="122.321" Width="269.87">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Style="{DynamicResource AppTextBoxStyle}"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnRed" Content="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnRed_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnGreen" Content="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="90,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnGreen_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btBlue" Content="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btBlue_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnNewWindow" Content="New Window" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnNewWindow_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace ColorApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnRed_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((App)Application.Current).appColors.appColor = Colors.Red;
        }

        private void btnGreen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((App)Application.Current).appColors.appColor = Colors.Green;
        }

        private void btBlue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((App)Application.Current).appColors.appColor = Colors.Blue;
        }

        private void btnNewWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is mostly a code-dump, can you boil it down to a very small [mcve], maybe start a new project and take out all the extra stuff?

Comment: Well, this is a sample workable project created to show what I am experiencing in a much bigger program.  The first half is working code using a local Windows Resource style that works as expected based on input on the original question.  The 2nd set of code is an example demonstrating how I am trying to accomplish this as an Application Resource.  The program runs but the TextBox color does not change as compared to the 1st code set.

Comment: `App` itself which inherits from `Application` is not a dependency object, I wonder if that is causing the problem. Shot in the dark: Try to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `App` and notify on `appColor`. That being said, there is something wonky in your construction I can't just put my finger on yet. There is one to many indirections in there I think... If I'm right you throw the whole `AppColors` class away and notify on the `App` class instead.

Comment: Ok -- AppColors was added because another StackOverflow article that highlighted App class is not based on DependencyObject unlike MainWindow which is why I was getting compile errors of "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property" mentioned first article comments.

Comment: The problem is you bind to `appColor` on `App`. If something changes there is no notification facility. You can either implement directly `INotifyPropertyChanged` and throw your helper construct away or shoehorn that somehow in there through a proxy which will be still needing a notification facility.

Comment: Updated sample code to reflect a more streamline version that is actually close to code in real program.  Been playing with other changes and I have actually got the text box text starting off Purple (although not reflect in the posted code sample) but the color is not changing on Button press -- but I understand why that is the case.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding was not correct

In App.xaml you need to change the foreground binding to:

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=appColors.appColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorToSolidColorBrushConverter}, Source={x:Static Application.Current}}"/>
```

in your style.

And change the `App` class in App.xaml.cs to:

```
public partial class App : Application
{

    public AppColors appColors { get; set; }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        this.appColors = new AppColors();

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

so it will get initialized and set correctly.

Just tried it and works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks.  It's working.  I got close a couple times on this never found the right combination of things.